# Accessing geolocation data on jpeg photos using delphi

Tags: delphi, jpeg

I'm trying to find a Delphi (XE2) VCL or procedure that extracts geo-data from smartphone photos. I'll also need to determine if no such data exists on the photo. Any pointers to the right process would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [`this topic`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging#JPEG_photos) for start.

Comment: Here is a Delphi open source link to read EXIF data on JPEG photos. [`ccr-exif`](https://code.google.com/p/ccr-exif/). Examples and documentation included. Read more about it on Chris Rolliston's blog, [`XE2 update for my image metadata reading/writing library (CCR Exif)`](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/xe2-update-for-my-image-metadata-readingwriting-library-ccr-exif/).

Comment: Thanks TLama, that reference was useful.  Earlier I purchased the source code for MiteC EXIF Reader but I couldn’t find any documentation on its use so I wanted to look further afield but didn’t come up with much. I’m not sure what EXIF standard is used by iphones so I will give Chris Rollinston’s library a shot.  Thanks for that heads-up LU RD. Since this is my first time posting to this site I’m not sure how I acknowledge the proceeding advice. I’ll have to have a look at this sites help documentation. Thanks and regards, Colin.